# Flutter/Dart Null Safety on _formKey.currentState.validate()?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I've just updated my minimum sdk in pubspec.yaml;

```
 sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

Now I have to change all my variables by declaring ? on all Strings and integers.

But what shall I do with the formkey?

```
 if (_formKey.currentState.validate())
```

Here's what Android Studio tells me but I'm not sure where to put the ?

```
The method 'validate' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.  Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
```

Any idea how I should convert this line to null safety?

And how about this?

```
 Future<File> file;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the first;

```
(_formKey.currentState!.validate())
```

And the next;

```
 late Future<File> file;
```

Comment: That might be valid for your specific piece of code, but this is not a general rule. For someone else, with the exact snippet of code in another context than your program, it might be wrong.